# How can I restrict puppet to run in particular time slot?

Tags: puppet

I want to run puppet agent only between 11 pm and 4 am, and it should be disabled otherwise. I see `runinterval` works only from the time puppet service was started.

Is there any way puppet can be configured to run in a particular timeslot?

Comment: IIRC puppet can be run from cron also... Did you find nothing about this in the documentation?

Comment: @Tensibai, can you share the link? I saw post which shows how puppet can as cron job but it does not work for windows.

Comment: For windows you'll have to setup a scheduled task, how is kind of dependent on your choices, puppet can set it up on a first run when you install it or you may set it up by another way (the same as you install puppet itself)

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?